# IF Radio is not selected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, error-handling

I'm working on a e-commerce site and I am having troubles.

I want to check if the user has selected one of the sizes:

```
var radios = $('input[name=product1]:checked').val();


IF (radios !=='1' || radios !=='2' || radios !=='3' ){
  errorMsg += '- Please Choose a Size \n';
}
```

It does not work and I have no idea why. 
I've looked in to it and haven't found a good solution for the problem.

Here is what happens: when I click one of the radio buttons it doesn't seem to catch it. The if statement returns true no matter what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `&&` not `||`, right now your if statement is always false!

```
if (radios !=='1' && radios !=='2' && radios !=='3' ){
  errorMsg += '- Please Choose a Size \n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was getting all mixed up in my mind. that worked perfectly.

Comment: @James_Invoking_Media no problem, glad I can help, please don't forget to mark the correct answer for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value  by:

```
  $('input:radio[name=Product1]:checked').val();
```

and changing your IF condition to use AND(`&&`) instead of OR(`||`).

Answer (score 0):

I think better way of doing this .. You can use the `length` and equal attribute selector with `:checked` filter selector like this:

```
if ($("input[name='product1']:checked").length > 0){
  // one or more checkboxes are checked
}
else{
 // no checkboxes are checked
}
```